# AngularUI select2 onChange method

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, jquery-select2

How do I go about doing something along these lines:

```
   <select ui-select2 multiple="true" on-change="onChange()" data-ng-model="select2Model"></select>
```

where in my controller, I have the onChange(select2OnChangeData) defined.

I tried adding this

```
    scope: {
        model: "=ngModel",
        onChange: "&onChange"
    },
```

to angular-ui, but that changed the scope variable and broke the rest of the functionality.

I'd really like to refrain from doing:

> .on("change", function(e)

Comment: Use ng-change for this

Comment: With `ng-change` the related method is executed multiple times when the directive is initialized.

Answer (score 2):

Good thing I did just this in my project:

**HTML**

```
<select data-placeholder="Select an asset" class="input-xxlarge" ui-select2="sourceAssetId" ng-model="sourceAssetId" ng-options="asset.id as asset.name for asset in assets"></select>
```

**Directive**

```
module.directive("uiSelect2", function() {
    var linker = function(scope, element, attr) {
        element.select2();

        scope.$watch(attr.ngModel, function(newValue, oldValue) {
            console.log("uiSelect", attr.ngModel, newValue, oldValue);

            // Give the new options time to render
            setTimeout(function() {
                if(newValue) element.trigger("change");
            })
        });
    }

    return {
        link: linker
    }
});
```

**Relevant Controller Code**

```
$scope.$watch("sourceAssetId", function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if(newValue) $scope.fetchAsset();
});
```

Comment: and what does the html look like that's using it?

Comment: How do you get the onChange method called though?

Comment: In my case, I don't. I set up a $scope.$watch on the ng-model attribute.

Comment: Gotcha - so you would do the same in the controller then instead?

Comment: This might work as a workaround. I'd rather expose methods though if there is a way. I'm using angular-ui's select2 directive though so I'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: One of the issues I had with this is that my watch gets hit multiple times during initialization so I would have to do some kind of $scope.initializing logic to ignore the changes during initialization. Feels cleaner to have an onChange attribute.

Comment: @HugoForte it's not cleaner. Use the Angular approach MikeRobinson outlined instead.

Comment: I tried, but the watch inside the controller fires several times on initialization which is not ideal. Also, the jquery plugin supports onchange, so why not expose it through the directive?

Comment: The plugin also supports 'added' and 'removed' which I want access to. If I do the watch - I have to go through the collection to figure out 1. if this was an add or a remove, 2 which items was added or removed.

Comment: I think you're still thinking about this from a DOM point of view. Keep in mind Angular is responsible for maintaining the state of the element now, not Select2. Options being added, removed, and selected should be handled by the controller.

Comment: I would equate having a watch on the model to using watch instead of ng-change for example - yes, it can be done, but I'd prefer not. Also, the overhead of figuring out what was added and removed from the collection is something I wouldn't want to reproduce in every controller using the plugin - I'd rather handle that once in a directive.

Comment: A little off-topic, `ng-options` does not play nice with `ui-select2`,  instead, `<option ng-repeat>` should be used.